# Работа с youtube_dl. 18+ видео. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

Я использую вот такой код(библиотека youtube_dl). Куки станадртные от youtube_dl.

```
downloader = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio', 'title': True, 'username': 'моя почта@gmail.com', 'password': 'мой пароль', "cookiefile": config.COOKIE_PATH})
```

Но у меня вот такая ошибка.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\a1\musicbot\commands\music.py", line 48, in _play_song
    song = await audiocontroller.process_song(track, ctx)
  File "D:\a1\musicbot\audiocontroller.py", line 147, in process_song
    r = downloader.extract_info(
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
    return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 824, in wrapper
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 628, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Users\b0tbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 598, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: Sign in to confirm your age
This video may be inappropriate for some users.
```

Comment: Замените значение `cookiefile` на это: n-VPqeSPWas

Comment: Не помогло.....